# Show that the series $\sum_{n=1} \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+x}$ is convergent, $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{-1,-2,\ldots\}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Show that the series $\sum_{n=1} \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+x}$ is convergent using only the comparison test, $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{-1,-2,\ldots\}$.

From D'Alembert criterion it is immediate that the series absolutely converges on the given set. However I'm asked to prove it with refering only to comparison test.

For any fixed $x\ge 0$ we have $\sum_{n=1} |\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+x}|=\sum_{n=1} |\frac{x}{n^2+nx}|\le x \sum_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^2} < +\infty$

I don't have idea for the case when $x\in (-\infty,0)\setminus \{-1,-2,\ldots\}$.

Comment: In fact, $~\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\bigg(\dfrac1n-\dfrac1{n+x}\bigg)~=~H_x~.~$ See [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) for more information. The formula is especially useful in extending the domain of the index to non-natural values.

Answer (score 3):

Hint for negative $x$: Look at the sequence
$$
\sum_{n = 1+ \lfloor |x|\rfloor}^\infty \frac{1}{n+x}-\frac1n
$$
and compare it, term by term, with what you already have.

Answer (score 2):

$|\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n + x}| = |\frac{x}{n(n +x)}| \le \frac{|x|}{(n - x)^2} \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{-1, \ldots\}$.

Use d'Alembert criterion.